# What is the effect of input on positive terminal of integrator?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am using opamp as an integrator and found one reference design in which Vin is given at negative terminal and 2.5V is given at positive terminal, in that case how Vout can be calculated and what will be the mathematical expressions ?

Comment: When analyzing an Op-Amp with negative feedback the following two rules are helpful: 1. No current flows into the inputs. 2. The inputs are held at approximately the same voltage. You should be able to analyze from there and work it out yourself

Comment: if input pos and neg are held at different voltages, then the output will be fully saturated pos or neg. If the amp is working as an amplifier, say there are components connected to the inputs that allow their voltages to be equal if the amplifier output has some specific voltage or in the case of an integrator rate of change of voltage, then see jramsay's comment.

Comment: You should put a link or picture in your question to this apparently strange reference design. I suspect you are misreading it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pRk4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the op-amp is balanced the current through R1 is (Vin-2.5V)/R1. Since an ideal op-amp has no input bias current, that is also the current through C1.

You know the relationship of voltage across C1 with current.

So the output voltage is Vo(t) = \$V_{initial} - t\frac{Vin - 2.5V}{R_1 C_1}\$. for constant Vin, for time varying Vin you will have an integral wrt time rather than a product.

Comment: Hi Spehro, Thank you!
What can be Vinitial ?

Comment: That's the voltage on the integrator *output* at t=0, which is the capacitor voltage + 2.5V. Initial condition.